# D3: update data with multiple elements in a group

Tags: d3.js

I have a combined bar / line chart. For each row in the input file, I create a group that contains multiple elements (lines, rectangles, texts):

```
var myGroups = svg.selectAll('g').data(myData)
myGroups.enter().append('g')
...
myGroups.append('line')
...
myGroups.append('polygon')
...
myGroups.append('text')
...
```

I currently just

```
svg.selectAll('*').remove()
```

and create everything from scratch every time the data are updated. However, I'd like to have a smooth transition for all elements.

I've gone through [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) several times, but I still don't understand how I can do it in my case.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The key is to handle all the selections, not just the enter selection:

```
var myGroups = svg.selectAll('g').data(myData);

// enter selection
var myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g");
myGroupsEnter.append("line");
myGroupsEnter.append("polygon");
// ...

// update selection -- this will also contain the newly appended elements
myGroups.select("line").attr(...);
// ...

// exit selection
myGroups.exit().remove();
```

There are two things here that warrant further explanation. First, elements in the enter selection that have had new elements appended merge into the update selection. That is, there is no need to set attributes on the elements in the enter selection if the same thing happens in the update selection. This allows you to append new elements and update existing ones without duplicating code.

The second thing becomes important on subsequent calls with updated data. As the elements you're binding the data to are not the ones that are actually drawn, the new data needs to be propagated to them. This is what `.select()` does. That is, by doing `myGroups.select("line")`, you're propagating the new data bound to the `g` elements to their children `line` elements. So the code to set attributes is the same as for the enter case.

Now you can simply add transitions where desired before setting the new attributes.

Comment: You're the wind beneath my wings!

Comment: According to the d3 docs, `select()` is supposed to return a single element.  But here it appears to select all the line elements in the statement `myGroups.select("line").attr(...);`.  And in my experiments, `selectAll()` did not appear to work. Could you explain the apparent discrepancy?

Comment: `myGroups` contains multiple elements and `.select()` executes the selection for each of them. That is, you're selecting a single element for multiple elements. `.selectAll()` probably didn't work because it doesn't update the data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff , do you know how to update this with the new d3 v4 API? I've been trying to get this to work with and without the `merge` method, without luck. Thanks so much for any advice you may have!

Comment: You should only need a merge after handling the enter selection.