# Incorrect SVG group being deleted

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to remove the bar that is clicked, but for some reason it is always removing the last bar instead. I think the answer may be in the following article (http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/), but I'm not sure if manually assigning a key to each element is necessary. I have spent hours trying to get this to work, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Div-based Bar Chart</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .chart rect {
        fill: teal;
    }
    .chart text {
        fill: white;
        font: 30px sans-serif;
        text-anchor: end;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data-field"></div>
    <button id="add-btn">Add Data</button>
    <p>Click on a bar to remove it</p>

    <script>
        var barHeight = 75, margin = 3, padding = 3;

        var chartData = [6,12,15,21,29,41];

        var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("class","chart");

        drawChart();

        function drawChart() {

            var selection = chart.selectAll("g")
                .data(chartData);

            // Remove extra bars
            selection.exit()
                .remove();

            // Add more bars
            var groups = selection.enter()
                .append("g");

            var bars = groups
                .append("rect");

            var labels = groups
                .append("text");

            // Update existing bars
            groups
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * (barHeight + margin) + ")"; })
                .on("click", function (d, i) { chartData.splice(i, 1); drawChart(); });      

            bars
                .attr("width", function (d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
                .attr("height", barHeight);     

            labels
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d * 10 - padding + "px"; })
                .attr("y", barHeight / 3 + padding + "px")
                .text(function (d) { return d; });

            // update list of numbers
            d3.select("#data-field").text("numbers: [" + chartData.join(", ") + "]");
        }

        // add more data
        d3.select("#add-btn")
            .on("click", function(d) { chartData.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100)); drawChart(); });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zxg02fdm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to make, with comments:

```
// Update existing bars; do not use groups here since it represents
// only the ENTER selection, and not ALL g elements
selection
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * (barHeight + margin) + ")"; })
    .on("click", function (d, i) { 
        d3.select(this).remove(); // remove appropriate DOM element
        chartData.splice(i, 1); 
        drawChart(); 
    });
```

And here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vk8z6n8m/).

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

After @loucatsfan asked me why not simply getting rid of `selection.exit().remove();` since it made no difference, I realized the importance of making my answer more *idiomatic*. So, I created an updated fiddle that leverages the `exit` selection and removes the need to manually delete the DOM element.

Also, and just as important, there are some subtle differences between handling updates for grouped vs. non-grouped elements (use of `select` vs. `selectAll`). So, I revised the code to more appropriately handle grouped elements.

You can find more info on the proper handling of grouped elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912274/d3-update-data-with-multiple-elements-in-a-group#24912466) and [here](http://www.fernoftheandes.com/blog/blog005/index.html). But here is the promised improvement:

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xk6recso/)**.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It was driving me crazy.

Comment: I appreciate you going the extra mile to give a solution that uses enter/exit/update pattern.  Although there are clearly other ways to solve this problem, I prefer following best practices. You are a gentleman and a scholar.  Thanks a million from me and all of the people who read this post.

Answer (score 2):

Check my solution here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/sydvpsfp/

Major problem was that you were not deleting all the old bars at the begining of drawChart function.
I had added this:

> ```
>         // remove any old bars
>         var oldBars=chart.selectAll("g");
>         if (oldBars.size()>0)
>             oldBars.remove();
> ```

Comment: I never got an email about your post, so I'm guessing it went to junk.  Anyway, I would like to get this working without removing everything first.  If I remove everything, then the exit method isn't needed.

Comment: In this case then you should just remove the clicked bar and rearrange other bars, without calling drawChart every time.

Comment: I can get this to work using DIVs, but not with SVG group elements.  See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/b51br444/