# Adding text to d3 bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some problems with adding text to my bars. I want to show the value above the bar, but i can't add a text to every bar.

Now my dom structure is:

```
g
 rect
 rect
 rect
```

What i want:

```
g
 g.bar
   rect
   text
 g.bar
   rect
   text
```

How can i add an parent (g) to my rect and add the rect and text as childs?

My code:

```
        bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(datasource)
            # bars enter
            bars.enter().append('rect')
                    .attr('class', (d, i) =>
                        "rect-" + i)
                    .attr('x', (d) =>
                        x(d.age))
                    .attr('y', height)
                    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
                    .attr('height', 0)
                    .attr('fill', (d) =>
                        d.color)

            bars
                .attr('fill', (d) ->
                    d.color)
                .transition()
                    .delay(200)
                    .ease(transition_ease)
                    .duration(transition_duration)
                    .attr('y', (d) =>
                        y(d.value))
                    .attr('height', (d) =>
                        height - y(d.value))

            bars.exit().remove()
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjbgtxqu/

Comment: plz provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for you code

Comment: Append `g` elements to start with instead of `rect`s. Then append the `rect` and `text` elements to those `g`s.

Comment: have you tried using insertBefore(); http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Comment: I've updated my question with an jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Lars advice (always a good one), here is a "template" to handle grouping of elements (e.g. `rect` and `text` under `g`):

```
group = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(datasource) # bind data to g elements

group.exit()
    .remove();

groupEnter = group.enter()
    .append("g") # append g elements

groupEnter
    .append("rect") # append rect elements

groupEnter
    .append("text") # append text elements

group
    ... # update g elements, if needed (e.g. add transform, add listeners)

group.select("rect")
    .data(datasource)
    ... # update the rect elements

group.select("text")
    .data(datasource)
    ... # update the text elements
```

You can see Lars excellent explanation of handling group elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912274/d3-update-data-with-multiple-elements-in-a-group#24912466) and my own brief explanation more recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310664/incorrect-svg-group-being-deleted#26422833).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to make it work, but instead all the bars are gone.  I think the principle of entering and exiting is not quite clear to me.

Check my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5h21yaw/

Comment: The problem is that you already have created `g` elements for the axis, so you have to distinguish the data g's by assigning them a class and then select them based on said class. I have made this change plus other syntactical ones to better leverage the idioms of D3. I have also set and placed your labels for demo purposes. You will need to improve their rendering. Here is the complete [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u0ghpbub/).

Comment: Wow, you're my hero! I forget there were multiple g's in my charts :(