# D3: update data in group selection with additional ('g')

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For my chart I had to create groups which contain several elements (line, rect, text). I did my setup like in this question: [D3: update data with multiple elements in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912274/d3-update-data-with-multiple-elements-in-a-group)

I defined my groups like this:

```
var group = groupContainer.selectAll('g')
    .data(items);
var groupEnter = group.enter()
    .append('g');
```

For each group element I appended a rect and did the update (later for my brushing event).

```
// append
groupEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'item')
    .style('fill', function (d) { return d.color; })
    .attr('x', function (d) { return x1(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y1(d.y); })
    .attr('width', '50')
    .attr('height', '50');

//update
group.select('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) { return x1(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y1(d.y); });
```

This works! Now when I want to put another group element between my group and the rect, the update won't work anymore.

```
// append
groupEnter.append('g').append('rect') // here is the change
    .attr('class', 'item')
    .style('fill', function (d) { return d.color; })
    .attr('x', function (d) { return x1(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y1(d.y); })
    .attr('width', '50')
    .attr('height', '50');

//update
group.select('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) { return x1(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y1(d.y); });
```

The selection `group.select('rect')` is the same as before. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I investigated my problem furthermore. It seems like the update method has the wrong data mapping. Without the group element (the working example), I get for

```
group.select('rect')
    .attr('x', function (d) { console.log(d); return x1(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y1(d.y); });
```

the ouput:

item 1
item 2
item 3
item 4
item 5
item 6
item 7
item 8
item 9
item 10

For the version with the group element I just get the output:

item 2
item 2
item 4
item 4
item 6
item 6
item 8
item 8
item 10
item 10

Some rects get drawn as well, but not all. I guess only 2, 4, 6, 8, 10. Whats wrong with the mapping? Do I have to re-map my data?

Comment: did you try `group.select('g rect')`?

Comment: Are you sure what you have isn't working? I was able to create a minimalistic working version: http://jsfiddle.net/vf01kanf/1/

Comment: I did edit my question with furhter information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage it by adding the optional data() parameter to match the elements.

```
var group = groupContainer.selectAll('g')
    .data(items, function (d) { return d.id; });
```

Can someone comment why I would need this optional parameter for matching when I use an additional append('g')?