# Update a grouped bar chart (transition or removal of groups of elements)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement an extended version of the [Grouped Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051). Everything works fine, except updating the plot. In a regular bar chart, I would do something like this:

```
function draw(data) {

  // Join the data with the selection
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data);

  // Create new bars if needed
  bars.enter().append("rect")
      ...

  // Update existing bars if needed
  bars.transition()
      ...

  // Remove bars if needed
  bars.exit().remove();
}
```

Works like a charm. Now i tried the same with my groups:

```
    var groups = chart.selectAll(".group")
            .data(data);

    groups.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "group")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.name) + ")";
            });

    var bars = groups.selectAll(".bar").data(function (d) {
        return d.values;
    });

    bars.enter().append("rect")
        ...

    groups.transition().duration(750).attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.name) + ")";
    });

    groups.exit().remove();
```

But: it only appends more and more groups on every update, no transitions or exits.
I am aware of this question: [D3: update data with multiple elements in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912274/d3-update-data-with-multiple-elements-in-a-group). However, I think did the setup just as described in the answer, without success.

**EDIT:** I am still trying to figure this out. I updated the fiddles.

Here is the working example without groups: http://jsfiddle.net/w2q0kjgd/2/

This is the not working example with groups: http://jsfiddle.net/o3fpaz2d/9/

I know it has been almost a month since the original posting, I tried to do something else in between and then have a look at this problem again, sometimes this helps. But I just cannot figure it out...

Comment: A shot in the dark, but I wonder if a `key` would help you in your databind on your nested selection:  `var bars = groups.selectAll(".bar").data(function (d) { return d.values; }, function(d) { return d; });`

Comment: That did not change anything...

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on jsFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to get back to this issue. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3fpaz2d/5/
It should update when you click on "sort by name" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the group before you select all the bars..

```
var groups = chart.selectAll(".group")
            .data(data);
    groups.enter()...

    groups.transition().duration(750).attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + 0 + "," + y(d.name) + ")";
        });

    var bars = groups.selectAll(".bar").data(function (d) {
            return d.values;
        });

    //add bars
    //update bars

    bars.exit().remove();

    groups.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also playing around with the same block and was trying to figure it out. In the end, this solution worked for me:

```
    var bars = g
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(data, function(d) {return d ? d.format_date : this.id; });

     var enter = bars
                .enter().append("g");

     bars = enter.merge(bars)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.format_date) + ",0)"; });

     var rect = bars
          .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })

     rect
        .enter().append("rect").merge(rect)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });
```

I think the trick here is that you need to update and merge it twice. One is for your x0 axes overall group and the other is for the bars within that group. Hope this also works out for you.