# d3.js : group dynamic SVG elements based on data

Tags: d3.js

I do have a `d3.scaleTime()` as x-axis and JSON data with dates, which should be represented as an `rect` on this x-axis, in order to mark the date as "reserved".

The simple way is

```
this.svg.selectAll('rect').data(dates).enter().each(function(d) {
   d3.select(this)
    .append("rect")
    .attr('height', desiredHeight) 
    .attr('width', desiredWidthFromTickToTick) 
    .attr('x', x(d.date));
}
```

But I would like to group `rects`, if they have consecutive dates, in order to be able to move the group around on the x-axis.

What I did / tried is in the enter / each function to check, if there is already a group with a date "next" to the current date.
If not, create a new group and append the current date-rect. 
If there is a group, get the group and append the date-rect to the existing group.

But now, the problem is, that the `rects` don't keep their data and / or I can't add the `rect` to the group properly.

Some (pseudo)code:

```
var rects = this.svg.selectAll('rect') .data(dates, function(dataElement) {
    return dataElement.id;
});

// add new date rects
rects.enter().each(function(dataElement) {

   var isNewDateGroup = true / false; // detect if date is "next" to another one

   if (isNewDateGroup)
   {
      var group = svg.append("g");

      var dateRect = d3.select(this)
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr('height', desiredHeight) 
                    .attr('width', desiredWidthFromTickToTick);

     group.append(function() {
        // works correctly, appends the rect and sets the data 
        return dateRect.select('rect').node();
     });

     // translate group to desired x(d.date)
   }

   else
   {
      var group = getGroupForDate();

      var dateRect = d3.select(this)
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr('height', desiredHeight) 
                    .attr('width', desiredWidthFromTickToTick) 
                    .attr('x', offsetToLastRectInGroup);

     group.append(function() {
        // does not work correctly, does not append the rect and does not set the data 
        return dateRect.select('rect').node();
     });
   }
});
```

Basically, the enter function does not work, if I append more then one SVG element, since the data gets confused and the appending as well. 
Any hints, how I can group my rects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912274/d3-update-data-with-multiple-elements-in-a-group) helped me to solve my problem:
Since `.select()` propagate the data to the selected elements, I just have to get rid of the selection:

```
var dateRect = d3.select(this)
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr('height', desiredHeight) 
                    .attr('width', desiredWidthFromTickToTick) 
                    .attr('x', offsetToLastRectInGroup);

     group.append(function() {
        return dateRect.node();
     });
```