# Appending multiple elements in a single Join

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to append multiple elements within the `enter` function of a single join using d3v5.

What is the *proper* method for appending multiple elements to a single group when using `selection.join()`?

The DOM structure I am trying to create looks something like this:

```
<svg id="chart">
    <g class="data-group">
        <rect class="data-rect" x="5" y="5" width="10" height="10" style="fill: red;"></rect>
        <text class="data-text" x="15" y="20">data1</text>
    </g>
    <g class="data-group">
        <rect class="data-rect" x="25" y="25" width="10" height="10" style="fill: green;"></rect>
        <text class="data-text" x="35" y="40">data2</text>
    </g>
    <g class="data-group">
        <rect class="data-rect" x="50" y="50" width="10" height="10" style="fill: gray;"></rect>
        <text class="data-text" x="60" y="65">data3</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I can easily produce this structure manually by looping through data
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgzab2n4/6/)

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
let o = data[i];
let g = d3.select('#chart')
    .append('g')
  .datum(o)
  .attr('class', 'data-group');
  
g.append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'data-rect')
  .attr('x',5)
  .attr('y', d => d.id * offset)
  .attr('width', 10)
  .attr('height', 10)
  .style('fill', d => d.color);
  
g.append('text')
  .attr('class', 'data-text')
  .attr('x', 15)
  .attr('y', d => d.id * offset + 9)
  .text(d => d.text);
}
```

I want to use `selection.join()` so I can cleanly take advantage of enter, update, and exit.

I can get *close* to this structure, however, I can't append the `text` element because it would be appended to the `rect` instead of the `g` (and ya can't append text to a rect!)
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgzab2n4/7/)

```
d3.select('#chart')
    .selectAll('.data-group')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
  .join((enter) => {
    return enter
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'data-group')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'data-rect')
      .attr('x',d => d.id * offset)
      .attr('y', 5)
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', d => d.color);
  })
```

Appending multiple elements then returning `enter` doesn't work either, it throws an exception
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgzab2n4/8/)

Comment: In `join`, you can do `const g = enter.append('g')` followed by `g.append('rect')` and `g.append('text')`.

Comment: Thanks @BallpointBen, this is exactly what I needed. I posted your response as an answer to the question, I think I did it correctly...new to this!

Answer (score 4):

See [BallPointBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496433/ballpointben)'s comment on my original question.

Multiple elements can be appended in a join by doing the following:

```
d3.select('#chart')
    .selectAll('.data-group')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
    .join((enter) => {
        let g = enter;
    
        g.append('g')
         .attr('class', 'data-group')

        g.append('rect')
         .attr('class', 'data-rect')
         .attr('x',d => d.id * offset)
         .attr('y', 5)
         .attr('width', 10)
         .attr('height', 10)
         .style('fill', d => d.color);

        g.append('text')
         .attr('class', 'data-text');

    return g;
  })
```

Comment: I believe BallPointBen's comment suggested making a reference to the appended data-group elements - `const g = enter.append('g')`. Here you've made a reference to the enter method, not the appended groups.

Comment: Both seem to work, I have used the two interchangeably since asking this question and haven't had any issues since. But thanks for pointing that out, you are definitely correct that my solved example does not match his response.

Comment: @rundy I tried the answer in d3 code integrated to my Next Js App, does not work. JabbaWook comment helped me solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if the data is updated after the enter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24912466/930949) to a similar question for the right answer.