# Why is g element found in enter but not in update step in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am parsing an xml string and display it as a tree in d3.js. I can build the whole tree in the 'enter' step, but now I want to make it interactive and pull out the configuration into an update step. I'm following https://stackoverflow.com/a/24912466 to implement the general update pattern but I can't seem to set the attribute to the g element outside the enter step:

```js
const svg = d3.select("#canvas");

const xmlAsText = `
      <root attrib1="foo" att2="foO">
      <child1 attrib1="ba">zwei</child1>
      <child2>eins</child2>
      </root>`;
treeDataXml = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlAsText, "text/xml");

let hierarchy = d3.hierarchy(treeDataXml.children[0], d => d.children);
  
nodesData = d3.tree()(hierarchy);

var myGroups =  svg.selectAll("g").data(nodesData.descendants());

myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g")
// 1) works          
//myGroupsEnter       .attr("class", "x");
// 2) doesn't work
myGroups.select("g").attr("class", "x");

console.log(document.getElementById("canvas").childNodes[0].attributes[0])
alert(document.getElementById("canvas")
              .childNodes[0].attributes.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="canvas"></svg>
```

with 1) I get

```
<body>
  <svg id="canvas">
    <g class="x"></g>
    <g class="x"></g>
    <g class="x"></g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

but with 2) it's just:

```
<body>
  <svg id="canvas">
    <g></g>
    <g></g>
    <g></g>
  </svg>
</body>
```

I would expect that with `myGroups.select("g").attr("class", "x")` the previously `enter`ed `<g>`s will all be selected and have their attribute `class` set to "x". Why doesn't this work? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selections are immutable, `myGroups` is an empty selection: it doesn't contain any DOM elements yet. As this selection is the update selection, this makes sense, there is nothing to update.

The selection `myGroupsEnter` contains the newly created elements. Entering elements does not modify `myGroups`, this remains an empty selection. This explains why `myGroupsEnter.attr("class", "x");` works and `myGroups.select("g").attr("class", "x");` does not.

*D3 v3 and earlier added newly entered elements in the update selection, which is why some examples might be misleading, but as this behavior was not explicit it was removed*

Often you want to combine the entered and updated elements into one selection, you can use:

```
let combined = myGroups.merge(myGroupsEnter);
```

This way regardless of whether you are entering all elements, updating all elements, or entering some and updating others you can modify all elements that exist (that are not exited).